# Accessing CDK Stack Resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

When creating a basic s3 resource with the following code

```
export class Test1Stack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);
    new s3.Bucket(this, 'sampleBucket', {
      versioned: true,
      removalPolicy: cdk.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
      autoDeleteObjects: true
    });
  }
}
```

Cdk creates the following resources:

- AWS::S3::Bucket
- AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
- Custom::S3AutoDeleteObjects
- AWS::IAM::Role
- AWS::Lambda::Function
- AWS::CDK::Metadata

I can access AWS::S3::Bucket AWS::S3::BucketPolicy properties by using

```
const s3 = new s3.Bucket(.......)
```

What object would give me access to the rest of the resources, for example if I'd like to overwrite the logical id for AWS::IAM::Role.

I imagine that I could create my own AWS::IAM::Role, AWS::Lambda::Function, AWS::CDK::Metadata and in this way I could use the same mechanism I am using for s3 to manipulate & override properties, but it is not what I am looking for.

I just want to be able to access the other resources at run time.

I have tried the properties from the constructor with no success.

I also understand that CDK does not recommend overriding resources.

Comment: The "autoDeleteObjects: true" property is creating the Custom::S3AutoDeleteObjects
AWS::IAM::Role
AWS::Lambda::Function resources. The property is read only. I think if I'd like to achieve what I want, to modify the stack I'd need to remove that property and create my custom resources, which don't make much sense.

Comment: If you want a little more control over what is created, you could investigate using the Cfn* constructs (e.g. CfnBucket) which provide more direct parity with CloudFormation. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_s3/CfnBucket.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the bucket policy, assuming it got auto-created, and change its logical id like so:

```
const policy = bucket.policy!;
(policy.node.defaultChild as CfnBucketPolicy).overrideLogicalId("MyBucketPolicy")
```

As for the IAM Role related to `autoDeleteObjects` it is also possible but a little bit more brittle. There's a custom resource provider mini-framework used. This means that the labmda is shared between all `Buckets` in a given stack that use `autoDeleteObjects`.

Still, it is possible to get a hold of the lambda itself like so:

```
const provider = this.node.findChild('Custom::S3AutoDeleteObjectsCustomResourceProvider') as CustomResourceProvider
const lambda = provider.node.findChild('Handler') as CfnResource
```

Comment: thank you, I managed to solve this using the long winded way, grinding down through nodes and children, but I was thinking there would be a better way. You are using the knowledge from the assets section. I didn't get there, by the time I was thinking about overriding resource - which is a bad thing, unless you really have a use case'

`const logicalID  = lambda.stack.resolve((lambda.logicalId))
    lambda.stack.renameLogicalId(logicalID, 'assets')`

this is the rest of the code, to actually override